# Maintain referential integrity without FK

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

Please suggest some of the best ways to maintain referential integrity without FK's in already existing database. Planning to remove the FK's from some of the tables. How can we maintain the referential integrity.

Comment: This sounds lkike a very bad idea. Why would you do that? Using foreign keys is how the DBMS guanrantees referential integrity. Without them, you'd have to built this logic yourself, if the DBMS allows that. *Maybe* it's possible to look up the parent table on inserts and updates in a trigger and throw an exception when the new value doesn't exist in that table. I don't know SQL Server well enough to say whether this is possible or not.

Comment: There are generally 2 ways to achieve referential integrity: foreign keys and triggers. So yes, FKs are not the only way, but it's definitely the cheapest and fastest way. What's the reason behind the decision to remove them? Does it have anything to do with reality?

Comment: What is the reason that you are going to remove the FK's?  Maybe that's also important to understand the problem.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Actually, planetscale does not support foreign keys, so here you have to have make it work without. And no, no foreign keys are not necessarily bad. Read more here: https://planetscale.com/docs/learn/operating-without-foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to have foreign key as part of your database design. Always leveraging something out of the box with RDBMS, is better, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.

Foreign keys, in addition to maintaining database referential integrity, also provide performance benefits in the execution of queries. [Read FK and performance benefits](http://dbadiaries.com/foreign-key-constraints)

If you don't want to have Foreign keys and want to ensure referential integrity, you can think of below options:

- Create stored procedure for all the inserts. The stored procedure first checks the existance of parent, before inserting record to child. Otherwise, it throws exception
- Create INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE triggers in the parent, child tables and handle the referential integrity accordingly
- If you have got ETL loads, you can think of having Lookups to handle the referential integrity before inserting data. Error rows can be moved to separate error destination.